# CLOSED - Puzzlingly long systemd boot times, don't know where to start

Tags: linux, boot, systemd, lubuntu

I understand that solving long boot times involves analyzing how long it takes to boot up what, but the output of `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze plot` has left me puzzled.

```
~ $ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 12.557s (firmware) + 4.516s (loader) + 3.732s (kernel) + 26.720s (userspace) = 47.526s
```

```
~ $ systemd-analyze blame | grep "\s[1-9]*\."
          8.989s keyboard-setup.service
          8.757s dev-sda2.device
          6.055s apparmor.service
          4.948s accounts-daemon.service
          4.446s NetworkManager.service
          3.383s gpu-manager.service
          3.134s systemd-udevd.service
          3.079s snapd.firstboot.service
          2.440s udisks2.service
          2.249s grub-common.service
          2.093s upower.service
          1.943s networking.service
          1.661s avahi-daemon.service
          1.461s rsyslog.service
          1.460s pppd-dns.service
          1.449s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.387s systemd-rfkill.service
          1.290s colord.service
          1.210s resolvconf.service
          1.192s apport.service
          1.188s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.187s systemd-remount-fs.service
          1.166s dev-mqueue.mount
          1.152s bluetooth.service
          1.032s lightdm.service
          1.013s plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

[image: Output of systemd-analyze plot]

### Information

The machine is a Dell Inspiron 5559; I've had it since February/March 2016.

```
~ $ uname -imporvs
Linux 4.8.0-32-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 13 14:30:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Distro is Lubuntu 16.10 w/LXDE.

```
~ $ sudo parted /dev/sda unit mib print
Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 953870MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start      End        Size       File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1.00MiB    513MiB     512MiB     fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      513MiB     937591MiB  937078MiB  ext4
 3      937591MiB  953869MiB  16278MiB   linux-swap(v1)
```

Worst part is, the times of the individual modules vary a bit (1 to 2 seconds, observed from following this problem since I installed Lubuntu), which means I would need to update `systemd-analyze blame` constantly or log a series of reboots and then make an average.

Can anyone tell me where I could *start*?

## UPDATE

Upgrading from 16.10 to 17.04 via `sudo apt dist-upgrade` changed the situation considerably.

```
~ $ systemd-analyze blame | grep "\s[1-9]*\."
         16.083s dev-sda2.device
         15.435s keyboard-setup.service
          8.015s systemd-udevd.service
          4.090s NetworkManager.service
          3.644s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          2.621s apparmor.service
          2.549s grub-common.service
          2.477s plymouth-read-write.service
          1.560s accounts-daemon.service
          1.107s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.002s colord.service
```

```
~ $ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @25.631s
└─multi-user.target @25.631s
  └─getty.target @25.631s
    └─getty@tty1.service @25.631s
      └─system-getty.slice @25.630s
        └─setvtrgb.service @25.407s +222ms
          └─systemd-user-sessions.service @25.245s +2ms
            └─network.target @25.245s
              └─NetworkManager.service @21.154s +4.090s
                └─dbus.service @21.147s
                  └─basic.target @21.139s
                    └─sockets.target @21.139s
                      └─snapd.socket @21.136s +2ms
                        └─sysinit.target @21.110s
                          └─apparmor.service @18.488s +2.621s
                            └─local-fs.target @18.488s
                              └─boot-efi.mount @18.387s +100ms
                                └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7930\x2d6EDD.service @18.198s +150ms
                                  └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7930\x2d6EDD.device @18.198s
```

[image: Output of systemd-analyze plot]
At least clear culprits are appearing.

## CLOSED

The post is being closed because I have migrated to another distro (Gentoo) where the problem has not arisen, so the question is no longer relevant.

Comment: Ok, one lead I have is that some of the services mentioned by `systemd-analyze blame` (in particular `keyboard-setup.service`) are SysVInit-style scripts located in /etc/init.d. Though I don't know how you would replace a script-based service...

Comment: `grep "\s[1-9]\."` any reason you're filtering out services with >10s load times? Put a `+` after the `]` to match one or more digits.

Comment: @JacobKrall I didn't exactly filter them out, it's just I didn't have any services with > 10s load times, hence the single digit. I did this in a hurry... and '+' didn't work for me, '*' did.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the bother. That's strange that `+` didn't work; it's one of the repetition operators in GNU Grep https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Fundamental-Structure

Comment: @JacobKrall I also thought it was strange too. Debug later.

Comment: @setun-90 try: grep -P "\s[1-9]+\."
The -P invokes the Perl regexp syntax for grep.

Comment: Consider this question as paused for the moment, I'll get back to it once the exam periods are over and I can concentrate on this again.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me where I could start?

**Run a Live Ubuntu Session (or any distro that comes with "try without installing" feature)**

Many a times Linux based distros take long time to boot or even fail to boot when there's some issue with a peripheral component like keyboard or NIC, etc. For example, my old laptop's keyboard's "Up" Key remains in pressed state without being physically pressed. Because of this the keyboard-setup.sh waits for a long time, fails to complete and finally I see a bunch of error messages that notify me of Ubuntu not being able to boot. Disconnecting keyboard during boot was the workaround for me to make it boot.

Testing your *hardware* for such type of errors would be a good starting point. If you know about a hardware issue with your laptop you can try to disconnect that component during boot (probably NIC or keyboard because you mentioned polktid and keyboard-setup.sh )

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the hardware, I hadn't thought of that. Though I should also have mentioned in the question that I did a distro upgrade to 17.04 and the boot times have changed slightly (with udevd now being the main culprit), but I do think keyboard-setup.sh is still taking a long time. I'll update.

Comment: Pls mention that in your question. Which version you upgraded from? Upgrading from LTS to a Release always causes problems. If you upgraded from 16.xx LTS to 17.04 you will have to do a clean install of 17.04 then. I insist to try a live session of 17.04. If live session is booting fine, a clean install will definitely fix things up.

Comment: Sorry, I did the upgrade in the meantime, after this question was asked. Boot times actually shortened by a second or two. But yes, I guess a clean reinstallation could do something. And btw I thought 16.10 wasn't LTS.

Comment: Another point to note, you cannot _officially_ update from an LTS (eg 16.xx, 14.xx) to a Release (eg 15.xx, 17.xx) or vice versa. You can update with an iso ofcourse but it always makes the system buggy. I guessed you have upgraded from iso and that's why I suggested to do a clean install. If this is the case, I will update my answer which might help some one else in future.

Comment: I didn't use an ISO, the offer to upgrade showed up one day through Synaptic and I then ran `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.